# Method 'Insert' of object 'Range' failed error

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a short piece of code that intends to, upon double click of a '+' sign on a spreadsheet, that it should copy the entire row where the '+' sign is and insert a new row directly below that is exactly the same.

If I try to add a row before I've added any text to the sheet there is no problem. But if I add text, not even to the line I'm attempting to copy, and then try to add a row I get a

> "Method 'Insert' of object 'Range' failed"

error, even if I have deleted the text before I do the copy. The insert itself seems to actually happen, but just triggers an error. If I use the Delete row first though, not even to delete the row with the text, the code works perfectly.When I debug the `Cells(Target.Row + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert` part seems to be the issue.

```
Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=strPwd

If ActiveCell.Column = 3 And Target.Value = "+" Then
    Target.EntireRow.Copy
    Cells(Target.Row + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert
    Cells(Target.Row + 1, 1).EntireRow.Select

    For Each Cell In Selection
        If Cell.Interior.Color = 13434879 Then
            Cell.ClearContents
        ElseIf Cell.Interior.Color = Black Then
            Cell.ClearContents
        End If
    Next

    Cells(Target.Row + 1, 4).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

ElseIf ActiveCell.Column = 2 And Target.Value = "-" Then

    Target.EntireRow.Select
    Target.EntireRow.Delete
    Cells(3, 4).Select

End If

ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=strPwd, UserInterfaceOnly:=True

End Sub
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Happy to provide more information if need be.

Comment: Try adding Application.EnableEvents = False at the beginning, and Application.EnableEvents = True at the end. Don't forget to set Cancel=True in both conditions under which you take action. If this helps, I'll write a formal answer, as there are a couple gotchas.

Comment: I have ran this several times without issue. There's something else going on here - anything else you can think of that may help? Do you have any other events beside the `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick()` event? I mean, there are definitely a few things in your code I would optimize, but nothing that would throw your particular error.

Comment: I'll try adding the Application.Enable Events = False, thnks! I do have security on the sheet as you can tell by the code. The only other thing is that I have some data validation and some conditional formatting, but even when I only put a bit of text in the cells not affected by these things I'm getting the error.

Comment: Try just `Rows(target.row + 1).entireRow.Insert`?

Comment: There's no need to select row before deleting (in general, avoid selections). What is the row number of `Target.Row`?

Comment: Ok, so I've removed the row selection in the delete part - and that is ok, but the row insertion actually wont work at all anymore. I tried BruceWayne's Rows(target.row + 1).entireRow.Insert suggestion - the insert works, but it adds at the top of the sheet, rather than inserting directly below where the user clicks. Also, @excelosaurus, the `Application.EnableEvents = False` addition now means that I'm just getting a 'protected sheet' error when I try to double click - I assume I've added it incorrectly? There are no other pieces of code in the workbook, only the Password and this piece.

Comment: Are there any merged cells, charts, shapes, formulas, conditional formattings, data validations, named ranges, etc. on your worksheet? Work in a copy of your file, using your original code (the one in the question). Start by removing the For Each loop. Then, gradually remove things from your worksheet until the point where only your + and - signs remain. You should at some point identify what was causing the issue. Be sure to report back here :-)

Comment: Seems that when I remove the conditional formatting in my sheet - I had both conditional formatting and data validation - the insert works perfectly even after adding text. Annoying - and weird that it will work before any text is added. Thanks for your help everyone!

Comment: Welcome to SO. The best way to thank us is to upvote the comments and answers that helped, and to mark answers as such (when present) so others can enjoy them.